# What is the command for primecoind and bitcoind to see my address?

Tags: bitcoind, primecoind

i just installed primecoind and bitcoind and datacoind and i want to know how i can get my address. what is the command options for it? I dont see it in the help list.

Answer (score 1):

With bitcoind up and running, you can use this command to check your addresses:

```
bitcoind listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
```

if you want to add a new address, you can use:

```
bitcoind getnewaddress
```

I don't have primecoind or datacoind installed, so I can't confirm if these commands work for them as well, but the source for both appears to be forked from bitcoind so it should work. The documentation for datacoind and primecoind seems a bit sparse on the net, but you can also try running

```
primecoind help
```

or

```
datacoind help
```

to check what options are available for them.